# Can you call a task directly in Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I understand that in x86 processors you can call a task directly by executing a `call` or `jmp` that refers to a TSS descriptor.

But I've never heard of calling a different process directly in this manner in Windows. Is this a feature of the processor that is hidden/unused by the OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access or use a TSS directly from user-mode code. This is protected by the CPU and the OS. You can only do it from code executing in the kernel mode.

Further, processes do not expose their TSS' (btw, there can be just one TSS in the whole system) for the purpose of calling or jumping to them nor are they (processes) designed for such use. You see, processes aren't subroutines to call. And the scheduler does not use TSS-based switching between processes.

So, not hearing about this is normal as this isn't something that's being done in practice.